# Test if Element ID is visible on Webpage using VBA

Tags: html, vba, web

My objective, using VBA, is to test if a certain ID is visible on a webpage (i.e. the user can see the box with the text "Processing".

The html is as follows:

```
 <div id="ESDSchedloading" class="TB_overlayBG" style="display: none;">
        <img id="imgESDloading" alt="Loading, please wait." 
             src="/images/loadingAnimation.gif">
        <span id="loadingText" style="display: block;">Processing...</span>
    </div>
```

I have tried the following vba code, but it always returns a 'Null' result even when the box can be seen.

```
debug.print ie.document.getelementbyid("loadingtext").getattribute("visibility")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can it be present before visible? Does it gain a visibility attribute when visible? What is the before and after html? I suspect the style attribute value might change to _display: block_ and so perhaps test for the value of that attribute. I don't find it hugely reliable a method but can work. Does the element disappear when loaded?

Comment: QHarr - thank you for your response. I have added more html. Does this help?

Comment: ie.document.querySelector("#loadingText").getAttribute("style") = "display: block;"

Comment: I tried your suggestion of ie.document.querySelector("#loadingText").getAttribute("style") = "display: block;" but it gives result of "True" even when the text is not displayed.

Comment: Is the html different when text not displayed? Maybe difficult to capture. For example, does imgESDloading  disappear or change text?

Comment: I cannot see any obvious changes to html. But there must be some kind of trigger for it to be displayed and then disappear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216143/discussion-between-jim77-and-qharr).

Comment: The key is normally to find what changes in the html. Does an attribute change value? Does a new element get added or an existing get removed. As these changes can be quick you (unless very familiar with js and can use something like mutation observers) will need to monitor closely the html.

Comment: I have noticed that the  style="display: none;"> part of <div id="ESDSchedloading" class="TB_overlayBG" style="display: none;"> does flash once the text box disappears

Comment: So maybe test for ie.document.querySelector("#ESDSchedloadingt").getAttribute("style") = "display: block;"    'or whatever it's initial value is